# How to show that $DA\cong D\operatorname{Hom}_{B}(T, T) \cong DT \otimes_{B} T$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, modules

I am reading the book Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras: Volume 1: Techniques of Representation Theory by Ibrahim Assem, Daniel Simson, Andrzej Skowronski.

Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra and $T_A$ be a tilting module. Let $B=\operatorname{End}_A(T_A)$. Let $D$ be the standard dual. That is $D(M)=\operatorname{Hom}_{K}(M, K)$.

On page 206, line 1, 2 of the proof of (b) of Lemma 3.7. How to show that $DA\cong D\operatorname{Hom}_{B}(T, T) \cong DT \otimes_{B} T$?

I think that 
$$ D\operatorname{Hom}_{B}(T, T) \cong D (D (DT \otimes_{B} T )) \cong DT \otimes_{B} T.$$
Do we have $ \operatorname{Hom}_{B}(DT, DT) \cong D\operatorname{Hom}_{B}(T, T)$? If this is true, then we have $D\operatorname{Hom}_{B}(T, T) \cong DT \otimes_{B} T$. How to show that $DA\cong D\operatorname{Hom}_{B}(T, T)$? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: if $T_A$ is tilting, what can you say about the map $A\rightarrow End_B(T_A)$, $a\mapsto (t\mapsto t\cdot a)$? Note that now $T_A$ is an $B$-$A$-bimodule.

Comment: Avitus' comment is explained in detail in the proof of Lemma 3.3 (c) of your book.

Comment: The first isomorphism should be clear, as Avitus and mt_ commented.  Note that the Hom is taken over left $B$-module in the RHS of this isomorphism.  The second isomorphism is also explained in the first line of the proof of part (b): $Hom_B(X,DT)=Hom_B(X,Hom_k(T,k))=Hom_k(T\otimes_B X, k)=D(T\otimes_BX)$, then you substitute $X$ by $T$.  The reason for the second equality (isomorphism) here is tensor-hom adjunction.

Comment: $Hom_B(DT,DT)\simeq Hom_B(T,T)$ as $k$-vectorspaces, as $D$ is a duality, note that if $T$ is a left $B$-module, then the Hom space in the RHS of this isom is taken over the category of left $B$-module, in contrast to the LHS, where Hom is taken over right $B$-modules.  Now the later abelian group is obviously isomorphic to $DHom_B(T,T)$ as $k$-vectorspace.  However, if you consider $A$-module structure of the two spaces, they are different, since one is a left module, the other is a right.

Comment: @Aaron, thank you very much.

Comment: @Aaron Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 1):

The first isomorphism follows from the fact that $A\cong Hom_B(T_B,T_B)$, as Avitus and mt_ commented, it's proved in earlier part of the book.

The second isomorphism is also explained in the first line of the proof of part (b): $Hom_B(X,DT)=Hom_B(X,Hom_k(T,k))=Hom_k(T⊗BX,k)=D(T⊗BX)$, then you substitute $X$ by $T$.  The reason for the second equality (isomorphism) here is tensor-hom adjunction.